# How to refer to correct 'this' in nested callback

Tags: javascript, this, golden-layout

In the following code, I get undefined reference for `this.lister` in the `create_components` method. I am trying to understand the meaning of `this` (apparently changes based on how you call the method) but it would be great if someone can point out the rule why `this` does not bind to the `ScreenCreator` and how can I achieve that.

Thank you!

```js
function ScreenCreator(config, container) {
  this.lister = new Lister();
  this.goldenlayout = new GoldenLayout(config, container);
  this.create_components();
  this.goldenlayout.init();
}

ScreenCreator.prototype.create_components = function() {
  this.goldenlayout.registerComponent('comp1', function (container, state) {    
    this.lister.init(container, state);
  });  
}
```

Comment: An arrow function will keep `this` context, eg.. convert  `function (container, state) { ...` -> `(container, state) => { ....`

Comment: Thank you guys, I think `self` is the cleanest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a variable in the outer portion (I usually call it `self`, but anything works) and use that inside.

```js
function ScreenCreator(config, container) {
  this.lister = new Lister();
  this.goldenlayout = new GoldenLayout(config, container);
  this.create_components();
  this.goldenlayout.init();
}

ScreenCreator.prototype.create_components = function() {
  const self = this;
  this.goldenlayout.registerComponent('comp1', function (container, state) {    
    self.lister.init(container, state);
  });  
}
```

Alternatively, you can use an arrow function, since they don't create their own `this` context.

```js
ScreenCreator.prototype.create_components = function() {
  this.goldenlayout.registerComponent('comp1', (container, state) => {    
    this.lister.init(container, state);
  });  
}
```

If you want a weird way to do it, which you probably shouln't use unless the others aren't working, here's that: (adding `.bind(this)` after function)

```js
ScreenCreator.prototype.create_components = function() {
  this.goldenlayout.registerComponent('comp1', (function (container, state) {    
    this.lister.init(container, state);
  }).bind(this));  
}
```

Comment: I had tried `self` method before posting but I think browser cached my page because it was not working. I tried again it works. I cannot use the arrow function, golden layout is complaining about it. Did not dig in on that yet, but I will check it.

Answer (score 1):

You could store `this in a variable` like

```
ScreenCreator.prototype.create_components = function() {
  let screenCreatorThis = this
  this.goldenlayout.registerComponent('comp1', function (container, state) {    
    screenCreatorThis.lister.init(container, state);
  });  
}
```